# Как из одного AsyncTask запустить другой AsyncTask, дождаться его завершения, и продолжить работу?

Tags: android, многопоточность, android-asynctask

У меня есть `AsyncTask`. Внутри `doInBackground()` есть `meteor.call` это функция из библиотеки *DDP Meteor* у нее есть `ResultListener` она асинхронная.

Как мне дождаться ее работы и после продолжить `AsyncTask`?

Comment: Для таких решений используйте JobScheduler.

Comment: А есть ли необходимость вызывать асинхронный метод из асинстаска?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте объект [CountDownLatch](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

1. Создаете объект перед запуском второго потока `final CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(1);`
2. После запуска нового потока делаете `cdl.await();`
3. В новом потоке по завершению делаете `cdl.countDown();`

Answer (score 2):

Вам надо разбить работу в doInBackground() AsyncTask'а на две части - до вызова Meteor и после, каждую из них оформить в отдельный AsyncTask. Тогда у вас получится три асинхронный задачи, которые надо выполнить последовательно, это уже понятная конструкция: из колбэка первой задачи вызываете запуск второй, и так далее.

Answer (score 0):

Можно переделать с помощью RxJava и RetroLambda так:

```
Observable.<String>create(subscriber->{
    //выполнится вне UI потока
    //делаем что-то долгое и тяжёлое (аналог первой части асинк-таска до вызова метода с колбэком)
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    //Запускаем асинхронную задачу
    someVar.someMethodWithCallback(new CallbackListener(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Result result){
            //тут делаем какую-то ещё долгую задачу
            //т.e. действие после асинхронной промежуточной задачи
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            //и наконец возвращаем результат
            subscriber.onNext("some result");
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable error) {
            subscriber.onError(error);
        }
    });
})
.subscribe(
    result->System::out,
    error->System::out
);
```